# Who is Sikander Raja?

Tags: cricket, trivia

There is a cricketer in Zimbabwe named Sikander Raja.

Can anyone tell me the details about him and his proper identity?

I would like full information about him. Where can I find it?

Comment: His background can be found described here: [_Raja enjoying the ride_](http://archive.thedailystar.net/newDesign/news-details.php?nid=196849).

Comment: Please refer to our [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in regards to research requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His name is Sikandar Raza, not Sikander Raja.

He is a Pakistani-born Zimbabwean cricketer. He emigrated to Zimbabwe with his family in 2001 and got selected for the Zimbabwe cricket team in 2011 because of his brilliant performances in domestic matches.

If you want to know more information about him, check his [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikandar_Raza) and his [ESPNcricinfo player's profile](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/299572.html).